# Why my minimum distance in Unity not working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, distance

UNITY 2D C#

I have a "Gear" object that spawns.

I have determined the minimum and max distance that can be between objects.

However, objects still spawn on other objects, covering (overlapping) them.

How to change it?

My script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GearsSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject theGear;
    public Transform generationPoint;

    public float distanceBetween;
    public float distanceBetweenMin;
    public float distanceBetweenMax;

    private int gearSelector;
    public GameObject[] theGears;

    private float minWidth;
    public Transform maxWidthPoint;

    private float maxWidth;
    public float maxWidthChange;
    private float widthChange;

    void Start()
    {
        minWidth = transform.position.x;
        maxWidth = maxWidthPoint.position.x;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        if (transform.position.y < generationPoint.position.y)
        {
            distanceBetween = Random.Range(distanceBetweenMin, distanceBetweenMax);
            gearSelector = Random.Range(0, theGears.Length);
            widthChange = transform.position.x + Random.Range(maxWidthChange, -maxWidthChange);
            if (widthChange > maxWidth)
            {
                widthChange = maxWidth;
            }
            else if (widthChange < minWidth)
            {
                widthChange = minWidth;
            }
            transform.position = new Vector3(widthChange, transform.position.y + distanceBetween, transform.position.z);
            Instantiate(theGears[gearSelector], transform.position, transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GearsSpawner : MonoBehaviour {


public GameObject theGear;
public Transform generationPoint;
public float distanceBetween;

public float distanceBetweenMin;
public float distanceBetweenMax;

private int gearSelector;

public GameObject[] theGears;

private float minWidth;
public Transform maxWidthPoint;
private float maxWidth;
public float maxWidthChange;

private float widthChange;

void Start (){

    minWidth = transform.position.x;
    maxWidth = maxWidthPoint.position.x;
}



public void Update (){

    if (transform.position.y < generationPoint.position.y)
    {
        distanceBetween = Random.Range (distanceBetweenMin, distanceBetweenMax) + 0.5f;

        gearSelector = Random.Range (0, theGears.Length);

        widthChange = transform.position.x + Random.Range (maxWidthChange, -maxWidthChange);

        if (widthChange > maxWidth) {
            widthChange = maxWidth;
        } else if (widthChange < minWidth)
        {
            widthChange = minWidth;
        }

        transform.position = new Vector3 (widthChange , transform.position.y + distanceBetween, transform.position.z);

        Instantiate (theGears[gearSelector], transform.position, transform.rotation);
    }
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

im guessing your objects are not exactly one unit in size, check the scale of the objects in question and adjust you minimum distance accordingly

Comment: This is the same object, only reduced and increased. How to adjust it?
Is it enough to not reduce the object, but create it smaller?

Comment: Well if you select it in the scene, and check the inspector it will tell you the scale. Usually when I import a model if it's scale is off it's a factor of 10. Meaning my scale shows up as 100 not 1, but yeah you can just reduce it to one if the scale is even on all three axis. If not youight have to do a little math

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure if I totally understand what your code is supposed to do.
However there are a few spots that look fishy and I have changed them according to my understanding of its intended purpose (marked with `FIX`):

```
void Update()
{
    if (transform.position.y < generationPoint.position.y)
    {
        distanceBetween = Random.Range(distanceBetweenMin, distanceBetweenMax);
        gearSelector = Random.Range(0, theGears.Length);
        widthChange = transform.position.x + Random.Range(-maxWidthChange, maxWidthChange); // FIX: the first argument of Random.Range must be the lower limit, the second one that upper limit
        if (widthChange > maxWidth)
        {
            widthChange = maxWidth;
        }
        else if (widthChange < minWidth)
        {
            widthChange = minWidth;
        }
        Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(widthChange, transform.position.y + distanceBetween, transform.position.z); // FIX: instead of overwriting the spawner's position, store the newPosition in a local and use that
        Instantiate(theGears[gearSelector], newPosition, transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry to write it, but it works terrible :) :) Now the object is spawning only overlap.

Comment: Well then you should describe the behaviour you are looking for in more detail. It's hard to fix a solution to an unknown problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understand your code right: you're trying to create a chain of gears from bottom to top by moving a random amount upwards, then a random amount left/right. If that's correct, then you might be overthinking it.

```cs
Rect boundaries;

void Start()
{
    boundaries = new Rect(
        transform.position, //corner 1
        maxWidthPoint.position - transform.position //size: corner 2 - corner 1
    );
}

void Update()
{
    if (transform.position.y < generationPoint.position.y)
    {
        float deltaY = Random.Range(distanceBetweenMin, distanceBetweenMax);
        float deltaX = Random.Range(minWidthChange, maxWidthChange);
        transform.position += new Vector3(deltaX, deltaY, 0);

        if(transform.position.y < boundaries.yMin)
            transform.position.y = boundaries.yMin
        if(transform.position.y > boundaries.yMax)
            transform.position.y = boundaries.yMax

        if(transform.position.x < boundaries.xMin)
            transform.position.x = boundaries.xMin
        if(transform.position.x > boundaries.xMax)
            transform.position.x = boundaries.xMax

        int index = Random.Range(0, theGears.Length);
        Instantiate(theGears[index], transform.position, transform.rotation);
    }
}
```